# julia type dependend function behaviour

Tags: function, methods, types, julia

I just tried out to define multiple methods for a function dependend only on a single input. The single input being different types and the behaviour should change according to the input type.

The problem is it's not working because only the last "version" of the function definition is being stored.

Here is the code:

```
abstract foo

type bar <: foo end
type car <: foo end
type dar <: foo end

f(bar) = "bar"
f(car) = "car"
f(dar) = "dar"

methods(f)
> # 1 method for generic function "f":
> f(dar)
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to implement different methods for a function dependend on a single input?

Comment: `f(x::bar) = "bar";  f(x::car) = "car";  f(x::dar) = "dar";` maybe just a typo? ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. In this case, no. Not a typo. The intention is to take an argument such as f(::car) and not a concrete object.

Comment: i still don't get the point. is `f(::bar) = "bar"` or `f(::Type{bar}) = "bar"` what you want?

Comment: f(::Type{bar}) = "bar" is it.

Comment: Got it. That was exactly the behaviour I was looking for. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f(bar) = "bar"` is equivalent to `f(bar::Any) = "bar"`,
here the `bar` in the function declaration syntax is an argument, not the type you previously defined. they are in deferent scope.

```
f(car) = "car"
f(dar) = "dar"
```

what happened here is `f(x::Any)` was overridden twice.

the right way is to define a function whose argument should be a type, so the type of that argument should be a `DataType`, precisely `Type{bar}` in your specific case.

```
f(::Type{bar}) = "bar"
f(::Type{car}) = "car"
f(::Type{dar}) = "dar"
```